# Catching exception thrown by method inside method

Tags: java, error-handling, exception

So let's say I have a class App which is where I am doing error handling and on this particular class I do

```
   try {
        layermethod();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Message.fileNotFound(filename);
    }
```

`layermethod()` is of the `Layer` class which is a "mask" class that I use to pass info from the App to the Core application and into objects.

So in the Class layer `layermethod()` is only defined as

```
 public void layermethod(Parser _parser) {
    _parser.throwmethod(_interpreter);
    }
```

And only in the Parser Class I do have the method that actually throws the exception

```
  public void throwmethod(Parser _parser) throws IOException {
        // method implementation
    }
```

Unfortunately as is, I get the error

```
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        _parser.throwmethod(_parser);
                         ^
```

Because I'm not catching the exception on the layer class.

Is there any way I can only do the error handling (catch the exceptions) on the App class only? Assuming I can't ditch the layer class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.  Either you can refactor `Layer.layermethod()` to also throw an `IOException`:

```
public void layermethod(Parser _parser) throws IOException {
    _parser.throwmethod(_interpreter);
}
```

or, you can explicitly add a try catch block in the above method:

```
public void layermethod(Parser _parser) {
    try {
        _parser.throwmethod(_interpreter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception here
    }
}
```

Given that you seem to want to bring the exceptions up into the `App` class, the former option is probably what you have in mind.